# Restore deleted partition

Tags: grub2, partitioning, grubrescue, restore

I had Ubuntu 16.x and Kali on my drive. Now I want to delete Kali and instead install Windows 10.

Accidentally I deleted Ubuntu in the Windows 10 installer, and closed it hoping it wouldn't save the changes. But it did and now I am getting the GRUB rescue screen. It shows `dev/sda` when selecting a partition in the Ubuntu installation GUI

Can I somehow restore the Ubuntu partition or is it gone from the partition table and the system for ever?

Comment: Whatever you do, **do not write anything to the disk.**

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use **Testdisk** from a live Ubuntu session. This is simple console tool but very powerful.

Install it by running

```
sudo apt install testdisk
```

and run it by typing

```
sudo testdisk
```

Choose **Create** at the first screen and follow on screen instructions.

if it fails to find your partition with **Quick Search** method then try **Deeper Search**.

[Here is a step by step guide to Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) from the developer of the program. Read that first if you are unsure about some options.